# How to get the URL parameter in PHP?

Tags: php, http, url, http-method

http://{{base_url}}/post/**857161551776694272**

I want to get the post_id(which is bold) in the above URL. Parameter does not contain any param name. (Its a PATCH method which also has a json body)

Comment: what is your `.htaccess`?

Comment: You can use codeignitor framework to achieve this. It is pretty simple out there.

Comment: thanks! it helped!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can get your url segments with parse_url e.g :

```
$uri_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$uri_segments = explode('/', $uri_path);

echo $uri_segments[0];
echo "<br>";
echo $uri_segments[1];
```

Comment: Its working, but not a very promising way. There should be a standard way to do this.